# Where can I find a global geocoding dataset based on postal code?

Tags: data, geocoding, postal-code, global

I'm looking to purchase a dataset (with a contract for updates) of postal codes to lat/long and city names for as much of the world as possible. Ideally the data would look like:

```
country_code  postal_code  lat        long       city
US            90404        34.0019    118.2853   Santa Monica
```

Where is the best place to get this data?

Comment: don't think it is available globally, country by country possible - UK is available in a different projection - codepoint open https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html

Answer (score 2):

You will find these data here: www.geopostcodes.com

Answer (score 2):

like the previous answer this is also a commercial provider:
DDS digital data services GmbH, based in Karlsruhe, Germany offers postcode data for most of the world. Much of their data targets at geomarketing applications and thus offers even subunits of postalcodes. 
http://www.ddsgeo.com/products/postal-boundaries.html

You would not get data in this level of detail anywhere for free. However I think postcode data for some countries is also included in OpenStreetMap. I think they use the tag boundary=postal_code for this.