# International postal codes

Tags: data, postal-code

I'm trying to plot spend data on zipcodes but only have US domestic zipcodes. Where can I find a shapefile/feature class for international postal codes? Point data is preferred but polygons will work.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search gave me the following results:

Paying datasets:

- http://www.zipboundary.com/index.html
- http://www.geopostcodes.com/World

Free datasets (country by country):

- http://index.okfn.org/dataset/postcodes/
- http://www.geonames.org/postal-codes/

Also, relevant post: [Where can I find a global geocoding dataset based on postal code?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104105/where-can-i-find-a-global-geocoding-dataset-based-on-postal-code)